# Single Notification but should deliver multiple pending intents when app is launched - Android

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, android-pendingintent, google-cloud-messaging

I am receiving multiple messages from GCM. When the app is running foreground or background i have no issues because i use broadcast receiver. But when the app is not running I would want to Queue the messages in the pendingIntent and keep it as part of the notification managers notification. So that when user clicks on the notification the mainActivity is launched and it is passed all the messages. I have posted the code below.

With current Code I am able to receive, only 1 message and that is the latest message, in the onCreate method of the activity.

To summarize the requirement

1. Application is not running. App Exited.
2. Call notify with pendingIntents on every new message received with Extra Field set to the  message
3. Just one notification message in notification bar ( let us assume "number of messages received 3" is seen in notification bar)
4. Now User clicks the notification
5. Application should be able to read all the 3 messages by accessing the pendingIntent

Hope i can find help!

```
// build intent
final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
        MainActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

notificationIntent.putExtra(CommonUtilities.EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);

notificationIntent.setAction("DUMMY");
// pending intent creation
int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
// set intent so it does not start a new activity
final PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestID ,
        notificationIntent, 0);




// create notification using intent
final String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
Notification notification = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
.setContentTitle(title)
.setContentText(formattedMessage)
.setSmallIcon(icon)
.setDefaults(Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL|Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)                   

.setContentIntent(intent).build();


final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(1, notification);



//Now in mainActivity:OnCreate 
//Receive

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {


    String inp = extras.getString(CommonUtilities.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    if (inp != null ) {
        doSomething(inp);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to start with this  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you are the one receiving the GCM incoming messages, and you are the one raising the `Notification`, it is up to you to arrange to store the details of the GCM messages in a file or database, and it is up to you to arrange to show all those details when the user taps on the `Notification`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So are you suggesting that pendingIntents is not the way to go ? Instead I write the content onto one of the storage options on android ? So it there no option to queue multiple pending intents behind a single notification in android ?

Answer (score 0):

Guys finally i used the following logic to solve my problem

Have a local array when receiving Intents.

If pending Intent Already Exists ( FLAG_NO_CREATE )
then 
  append the array with the new message and update the pending Intent
  This way the EXTRA will have old + new message in an array
else
  Clear the old message array because the notification has already been cleared.
  Now add the new EXTRA with ( FLAG_UPDATE CURRENT)
End

Then Notify

Now when user clicks on the single notification a new activity is launched.

In MainActivity Oncreate I read the intent data and go in a loop and all the messages that I would have missed when the app was not running!

Ofcourse not aware of how heavy it would be on the notification bar if the user does not click on the notification for a long time!

Comment: This also assumes that the user does not turn off their phone, reboot their phone, or accidentally dismiss the `Notification` (e.g., via "clear all"). Talented programmers do not attempt to use a `Notification` as a replacement for a persistent data store.